# How many overloads of 'Configure' method are possible in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

The Configure method is working like magic in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

**Scenario 1**

When a new project is created, the framework scaffolds the following method signature:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

No surprises that the application works with this signature, because I can presume that the ASP.NET Core framework expects the signature to be as is.

**Scenario 2**

The second parameter IWebHostEnvironment is removed:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
```

Application works.

**Scenario 3**

Injected my DbContext added to IServiceCollection in 'ConfigureServices' method along with logger:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILogger<Startup> logger, VegaDbContext vegaDbContext)
```

Surprisingly, application works. Looks like the framework is capable enough to resolve types added to service collection. Good sign.

Inline is implementation of ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<VegaDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                configuration.GetConnectionString("VegaDb")));
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

**Scenario 4**

Injected the WeatherForecastController, which I presume gets added to IServiceCollection via services.AddControllers():

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, WeatherForecastController weatherForecastController)
```

Application does not work. The following exception is thrown:

> System.Exception: 'Could not resolve a service of type
> 'Vega.Controllers.WeatherForecastController' for the
> parameter 'weatherForecastController' of method 'Configure' on type
> 'Vega.Startup'.'

Can some one explain how the method invocation is actually done by the framework and how it is capable of resolving few types like the *ILogger* and *VegaDbContext* but not the *WeatherForecastController*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works by using the dependency injection infrastructure. The arguments to `Configure` are retrieved from the web host's `ServiceProvider`. The keyword here is "service"--by default controllers are **not added as services** to the service collection.

In order to access controllers via dependency injection you need to call the `AddControllersAsServices` extension method for [`IMvcCoreBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvccorebuilderextensions.addcontrollersasservices?view=aspnetcore-3.1) or [`IMvcBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvcbuilderextensions.addcontrollersasservices?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in  your `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddControllersAsServices();
// or
services.AddControllersWithViews() 
        .AddControllersAsServices();
// or
services.AddMvc()
        .AddControllersAsServices();
```